# Ingesting websocket with FFMPEG or Gstreamer

Tags: websocket, ffmpeg, gstreamer

I'm searching to understand how to ingest WebSocket video stream with FFMPEG or Gstreamer.

I know I can ingest RTMP or RTSP in both softwares but ingesting WebSocket could increase reliability in the system.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure you need to use websocket to do that ? RTMP is TCP based so you have reliability.

With Gstreamer you could use :
appsrc with libsoup websocket client implementation.

Here an example libsoup implementation :
https://github.com/david7482/libsoup_websocket_client/blob/master/websocket_client.c

Here an example of appsrc gstreamer
https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/tutorials/basic/short-cutting-the-pipeline.html?gi-language=c

Best regards

Comment: There is possibility to receive and use WS video stream in my app so, I need to be able to ingest from WS and pipe it to opencv later